# Count the type of tasks executed by a windows service c#

Tags: c#, static, windows-services

I have a windows service developed using c#. This service keeps looking into a particular folder path say `inputfolder`, if there is any new text file added, it picks up the file, process it and generates an output and writes it into another log file and deletes the file from the `inputfolder`.

Now the data in `inputfolder` can be of different types, say `TypeA` and `TypeB`  for example. This type is known after reading the data in the text file. Each file has either `TypeA` or `TypeB` and not both.I'm able to read the txt file and get the type of file.

My requirement here is at the end of the day, I should be able to tell how many `TypeA` tasks have run and how many `TypeB` tasks have run.So for this I'm thinking of doing one of the following:

1. Declare a static variables ,say `countA` and `countB` in the application and as soon as I get the type, increment the appropriate variable. But if for some reason , the service has to be stopped and started in between the day, I will loose the data.
2. Write these details into a separate file say txt or log file. Read the file first, get the existing count, increment it and overwrite the new value again.

Can any one suggest , which is the best way to do this. If anyone feels that the above method is very crude way of doing, kindly guide/suggest me the better way of doing it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not down vote if the question is wrong, instead help me correct it.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say it depends of your requirements. if the counter value is important it's really possible to lose theme by any fault in service and you should store latest counter value locally.

And for the scenario of how and where to store counter value there is multiple choices :

- Store the counter on file in disk and keep file uptodate
- Store the counter in registry key

You code should be something like this :

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        var result = IncCounter(@"D:\1.txt", FileType.TypeA);

        Console.WriteLine($"TypeA : {result.FileTypeACounter} - TypeB : {result.FileTypeBCounter}");

        Console.Read();
    }

    public enum FileType
    {
        TypeA,
        TypeB
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class FileTypeCounter
    {
        public int FileTypeACounter { get; set; }
        public int FileTypeBCounter { get; set; }
    }

    public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
        }
    }

    public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public static FileTypeCounter IncCounter(string counterFilePath, FileType fileType)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileTypeCounter = new FileTypeCounter { FileTypeACounter = 0, FileTypeBCounter = 0 };

            if (!File.Exists(counterFilePath))
            {
                if (fileType == FileType.TypeA)
                    fileTypeCounter.FileTypeACounter++;
                else
                    fileTypeCounter.FileTypeBCounter++;

                WriteToBinaryFile<FileTypeCounter>(counterFilePath, fileTypeCounter);
                return fileTypeCounter;
            }

            fileTypeCounter = ReadFromBinaryFile<FileTypeCounter>(counterFilePath);

            switch (fileType)
            {
                case FileType.TypeA:
                    fileTypeCounter.FileTypeACounter++;
                    break;

                case FileType.TypeB:
                    fileTypeCounter.FileTypeBCounter++;
                    break;
            }

            WriteToBinaryFile<FileTypeCounter>(counterFilePath, fileTypeCounter);

            return fileTypeCounter;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your example above is very helpful. But , since I have to store 2 counter values, how do I differentiate between those 2 types. Say suppose the file has Count of TypeA : 13 (next line) Count of TypeB : 15 , how do I read it differently?

Comment: I change the code to serialize entire class into a binary file and vice versa. you can add more additional fields to "FileTypeCounter" class without need to change the code.

Comment: I have tried the above code. It is writing     ÿÿÿÿ        in the text file.

Comment: That's normal behavior.The entire class got serialized and stored in file, you can't read the content by text editor but the code cloud deserialize the file and read the content. i change the code again to view the result, check it and read the code carefully to understand what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Either

- Store it in memory, and persist the data to the file or the registry when it changes.
- Or store it in a db, the same, or create a table with a task and start date. You can query it in all sorts of ways

When the service loads read that data, store it in memory.

Job done

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The task has to be done without using the database. Can you explain the first point, what do you mean by store in memory? You mean write on a file?